# Java Swing: Select specefic row of Jtable after filtering data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The task is to filter data in jTable and pass selected values. This issue is that after filtering the data in jTable, it outputs the old value, that were at that position before filtering.

Suppose I have a table having one column, values are 1,2,3,4,5,6. After filtering I got only one value in the jTable, let's say, 6. So, it should output 6, but the output is 1. as 1 is there in the table before filtering. In the below code, first function filters the table according to the text provided in the textfield. The second function output selected value. How to update the jTable, so it gives me output on the basis of filtered data not on the basis of original table. Thank You.

```
private void jTextField_searchRecordKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                    

        DefaultTableModel table=(DefaultTableModel)this.jTable_Search.getModel();
        String query=this.jTextField_searchRecord.getText();

        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr=new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
        jTable_Search.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + query));
    }                                                   

    private void jButton_LocateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
       int column = 0;
       int rows[]=this.jTable_Search.getSelectedRows();

       for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
           String value = jTable_Search.getModel().getValueAt(rows[i], column).toString();
           System.out.println(value);
       }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection index in the table and in the model are two different thing. But you can convert one to another. `JTable` API has some conversion methods. In your case is the method `convertRowIndexToModel` is important. So your code should look like:

```
private void jButton_LocateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
   int column = 0;
   int rows[]=this.jTable_Search.getSelectedRows();

   for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
       int modelRow = jTable_Search.convertRowIndexToModel(rows[i]);
       String value = jTable_Search.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, column).toString();
       System.out.println(value);
   }       
}
```

Another possibility is to use the method `getValueAt` of your table.

```
private void jButton_LocateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
   int column = 0;
   int rows[]=this.jTable_Search.getSelectedRows();

   for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
       String value = jTable_Search.getValueAt(rows[i], column).toString();
       System.out.println(value);
   }       
}
```

Comment: @john Glad to help you. I've added another solution ;).

Comment: Yes, the second one is simplest. I was reading about difference between the model and table and found that: 
To display a JTable create a JTable and set corresponding table model to it.
 Any time, if we want to change the data in that table, change the data in the model, then the changes will reflect in view.

Comment: @john it's correct, but the methods `JTable.getValueAt` and `JTable.setValueAt` can also be used to simplify your code.

Comment: Acknowledged, Thank You.

Comment: How to add the selected value to another jTable??

Comment: @john Please post it as a new question. Also please provide [mcve] which demonstrates your problem, so I (or another user) can better understand what you want. This short question is too broad for me.